# Having trouble understanding the flow of this update function

Tags: javascript, function, object, if-statement

Okay, I have a record collection object:

```
var collection = {
    "2548": {
      "album": "Slippery When Wet",
      "artist": "Bon Jovi",
      "tracks": [ 
        "Let It Rock", 
        "You Give Love a Bad Name" 
      ]
    },
    "2468": {
      "album": "1999",
      "artist": "Prince",
      "tracks": [ 
        "1999", 
        "Little Red Corvette" 
      ]
    },
    "1245": {
      "artist": "Robert Palmer",
      "tracks": [ ]
    },
    "5439": {
      "album": "ABBA Gold"
    }
};
```

The code is updated, with the following function below:

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value){
   if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {
   if(collection[id][prop]) {
    collection[id][prop].push(value);
   }
   else {
    collection[id][prop]=[value];
   }
  } else if (value !== "") {
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  } else {
    delete collection[id][prop];
  }

  return collection;

}
```

I'm looking for some clarification on how the above code snippet functions. I read it as something like:

```
if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {
   if(collection[id][prop]) {
    collection[id][prop].push(value);
   }
```

If 'prop' is equal to tracks and the value is not blank, proceed into the updating portion of the function. The next part, which I'm not certain of, seems to say something like 'if collection's id and prop have a value, push said id and prop into the collection.

The next part I'm definitely a little lost on:

```
else {
    collection[id][prop]=[value];
   }
```

Starting with the above, I'm unclear if the purpose of this else statement is to just verify whether the information is already contained within the array.

```
else if (value !== "") {
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  } else {
    delete collection[id][prop];
  }
```

Finally, the above seems to test whether just the value is blank and, if it's not, it inserts said value into the array. If all conditions fail, the id and prop aren't added to the array. I don't feel I'm way off on this, but if somebody could help clarify some of the confusion, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I explain, how this works:

`collection[id][prop]`

you have an object like this:

```
var collection = {
  "ID_1": {
    "PROPERTY_A": "AAA"
  }
}
```

To access the `PROPERTY_A` inner the object which is under the property `ID_1` in `collection`

you can do this:

`collection["ID_1"]["PROPERTY_A"] // -> "AAA"`

you can also set the value like this

`collection["ID_1"]["PROPERTY_A"] = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"`

OK, lets check the code:

```
// if the prop is "tracks", it should be an array, there are many tracks... 
// so it should be handled like an array
if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {

   // does "tracks" exists for this item?
   if(collection[id][prop]) {

    // yes.. then push it into the array
    collection[id][prop].push(value);

   } else {
   // otherwise, (when "tracks" does not exist)
   // create the array and put the value as first item

     collection[id][prop] = [value];
   }
```

The above code could be simplified to this:

```
// so it should be handled like an array
if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {
  // set it to the same value, if the value is not falsey (null, 0, undefined) or make it to an array..
  collection[id][prop] = collection[id][prop] || [];      
  // push the value to it
  collection[id][prop].push(value)
```

The next thing:

```
// prop is not "tracks", but could be an empty string "", check it
else if (value !== "") {
    // Ok, the value is not an empty string
    // set the value to the prop
    collection[id][prop] = value;
} else {
    // If this is an empty string == "", then delete this property
    delete collection[id][prop]; 
}
```

Try to understand it, this are the very basics, if you have a special question, please make it as precisely as possible.

Comment: That makes sense, just a quick question. The [id][prop]=value portions of the code, these are applying tests to various levels of the array right? For instance, id = 2468, prop = "album", "artist", "tracks", and the value is whatever we are applying to said property? @webdeb

Comment: yes, but when `[id]["tracks"]` is an array, you should do `[id]["tracks"].push(value)`